# Email notification for failed SSH login

Tags: centos, ssh, email, login

Can someone tell is there a way to receive an email for failed SSH login? I already have Fail2Ban but as understood I can receive only email's for banned IP's ...
Using CentOS 7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you researched/tried? What are your specific requirements (I.E., do you want an email immediately after each failed attempt? Or will an hourly/daily summary suffice? and so on...)?